# Screen flickering loop on boot loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dual-boot with Windows 10.
Occasionally when I start or reboot the Ubuntu system I get stuck in a loop of screen flickering at Ubuntu loading screen. So, I force shutdown and sometimes it get back to normal. 
What can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show me `grep -i GRUB_GFXMODE /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/default` # change directory

`sudo -H gedit grub` # edit the grub settings

Find:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Check for screen issues.

**Update #1:**

Then try this...

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Comment: This didn't solve it. The problem occurs right after I choose Ubuntu in GRUB.  I made a video of the issue. Thank you anyway. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eXBRLEEyio

Comment: @TarcizioMatheusZanfolin Please try Update #1 in my answer. Report back.